# Docker build error OCI runtime create failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build an agent on the linux machine using docker. Everything was working fine and i was able to create the agent. But suddenly it was showing offline. When i tried to recreate the agent it was throwing below error:-

```
ERROR: for build-agent_dl-build-agent_1  Cannot start service dl-build-agent: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"write /proc/self/attr/keycreate: permission denied\"": unknown

ERROR: for dl-build-agent  Cannot start service dl-build-agent: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"write /proc/self/attr/keycreate: permission denied\"": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

even if i am trying to run a simple docker command  'docker run hello-world' i am getting below error,

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:430: container init caused \"write /proc/self/attr/keycreate: permission denied\"": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context cancelled
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What commands are you using to create agent? What is this agent for?

Comment: @harindersingh I am trying to run docker-compose down and docker-compose up -d --build commands. However, question is why i am not able to create a simple hello-world container? Why i am getting that error?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870478/cannot-start-docker-container-in-docker-ce-on-oracle-linux)? It may help.

Comment: @leopal I saw this but i did not understand it correctly. what is "updating container-selinux"? I am using Linux machine not the centos. 

Even I was able to run all the above commands mentioned in the question earlier. Why i am getting these issues now?

Comment: @leopal Thanks for the suggestion. It solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below command solved my issue,
sudo semanage permissive -a container_runtime_t

Please follow below link for more details,

[Cannot start docker container In docker CE on oracle linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56870478/cannot-start-docker-container-in-docker-ce-on-oracle-linux)

Thanks @leopal for suggestion.

Comment: I got: ValueError: SELinux policy is not managed or store cannot be accessed.